# send() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i am trying to make it say the name of the user that did **~milk**, it only produces the error when you type in discord **~milk**
here is the code that produces the error:

```
async def on_message(message):
   if message.author == client.user:
       return
   if message.content.startswith('~milk'):
       await message.channel.send(message.author, 'is blessed by the Baltic Gods of Dairy')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`send()` takes only 1 to 2 positional arguments meaning it could be either `send()` or `send(something here)`, in your code you can use either f string or , concatenation of strings like :-

```
await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.display_name} is blessed by the Baltic Gods of Dairy.")
```

or

```
await message.channel.send(str(message.author.display_name)+"is blessed by Baltic gods of Dairy.")
```

Answer (score 6):

`channel.send()` takes only one argument (and the implicit self which makes it appear like 2)

You can write it like this:

```
await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention} is blessed by ...')
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to pass 3 arguments to the discord instead of 2. When you try concatenate strings while passing them as arguements, always use +. If you use a comma, it treats them as separate arguments and therefore gets 3 different parameters(self,author and your message) instead of 2(self and message).

```
async def on_message(message):
   if message.author == client.user:
       return
   if message.content.startswith('~milk'):
       await message.channel.send(message.author+ 'is blessed by the Baltic Gods of Dairy')
```